# Indicate groups of items using CSS

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a an untitled list with items:

```
<ul>
    <li id="msg_0" data-user="usr_0">Message 0</li>
    <li id="msg_1" data-user="usr_1">Message 1</li>
    <li id="msg_2" data-user="usr_1">Message 2</li>
    <li id="msg_3" data-user="usr_2">Message 3</li>
    <li id="msg_4" data-user="usr_2">Message 4</li>
    <li id="msg_5" data-user="usr_2">Message 5</li>
    <li id="msg_6" data-user="usr_1">Message 6</li>
    <li id="msg_7" data-user="usr_1">Message 7</li>
    <li id="msg_8" data-user="usr_0">Message 8</li>
    <li id="msg_9" data-user="usr_0">Message 9</li>
</ul>
```

This renders thusly:

[image: Message list]

Is there a way, using CSS(3), to indicate the sequence of items that are from the same users, e.g. by giving them some margin. Like this:

[image: Grouped message list]

The HTML snippet is taken from an Angular2 app, so it would also be possible to use another attribute (different from 'data-user').

usr_0, usr_1, usr_2,... are IDs and therefor can't be hardcoded in the CSS file.

Comment: `li` elements don't technically support `name` attribute.  Why not make that a class?

Comment: Or use a `data-` attribute.

Comment: Adjusting the margin implies a hierarchy -- that some items are a sub-list of others. This is an inappropriate way to indicate they belong to different users. Unless I'm misunderstanding something, I'd suggest using a distinct icon and/or color for each user instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute selectors and the adjacent sibling selector.

```css
[name="usr_0"] + [name="usr_0"], [name="usr_1"] + [name="usr_1"], [name="usr_2"] + [name="usr_2"] {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li id="msg_0" name="usr_0">Message 0</li>
    <li id="msg_1" name="usr_1">Message 1</li>
    <li id="msg_2" name="usr_1">Message 2</li>
    <li id="msg_3" name="usr_2">Message 3</li>
    <li id="msg_4" name="usr_2">Message 4</li>
    <li id="msg_5" name="usr_2">Message 5</li>
    <li id="msg_6" name="usr_1">Message 6</li>
    <li id="msg_7" name="usr_1">Message 7</li>
    <li id="msg_8" name="usr_0">Message 8</li>
    <li id="msg_9" name="usr_0">Message 9</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, indeed. But the problem is that usr_0, usr_1, usr2,... are IDs, which are unknown beforehand.

Comment: @FlockDawson ah if that's a requirement for the question, be sure to add it to your question. You didn't mention that. I don't think that's possible with just CSS though.

Comment: @FlockDawson Michael's right; there's no way in CSS to match unknown values, especially against each other. You'll need to use JavaScript to do value comparisons and then assign a class.

Comment: @FlockDawson You can still use Michael's logic here, and when you create the messages you also dynamically create and append a style element with the given logic and CSS selector for each user that exists on the message queue

Answer (score 0):

You could do something similar to **@MichaelCoker**'s answer that uses the sibling selector. Essentially you toggle between two flags that you apply to the markup. In my example I've used a class but can be done other ways, i.e. `data-` attribute.

This solution will require some intervention on the backend or template engine. If that's possible, all you need to do is toggle between the two flags every time the user changes. Then apply a rule to those two flags.

```css
.alpha + .alpha,
.beta + .beta {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li id="msg_0" class="alpha" data-user="usr_0">Message 0</li>
    <li id="msg_1" class="beta" data-user="usr_1">Message 1</li>
    <li id="msg_2" class="beta" data-user="usr_1">Message 2</li>
    <li id="msg_3" class="alpha" data-user="usr_2">Message 3</li>
    <li id="msg_4" class="alpha" data-user="usr_2">Message 4</li>
    <li id="msg_5" class="alpha" data-user="usr_2">Message 5</li>
    <li id="msg_6" class="beta" data-user="usr_1">Message 6</li>
    <li id="msg_7" class="beta" data-user="usr_1">Message 7</li>
    <li id="msg_8" class="alpha" data-user="usr_0">Message 8</li>
    <li id="msg_9" class="alpha" data-user="usr_0">Message 9</li>
</ul>
```

Pseudo example.

```js
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    msgs = [
     { msg: 'Message', user: 0 },
     { msg: 'Message', user: 1 },
     { msg: 'Message', user: 1 },
     { msg: 'Message', user: 2 },
     { msg: 'Message', user: 2 },
     { msg: 'Message', user: 2 },
     { msg: 'Message', user: 1 },
     { msg: 'Message', user: 1 },
     { msg: 'Message', user: 0 },
     { msg: 'Message', user: 0 }    
    ],
    $li,
    flag,
    prevUser;
    
msgs.map( function ( msg, i ) {

  if ( prevUser !== msg.user ) {
   flag     = 'alpha' === flag ? 'beta' : 'alpha';
    prevUser = msg.user;
  }
  
  $li = $( '<li>', {
    'class':      flag,
    'id':         'msg_' + i,
   'text':       msg.msg + ' ' + msg.user,
    'data-user':  'user_' + msg.user
  } );
  
  frag.appendChild( $li[ 0 ] );

} );

$( '<ul>' )
  .append( frag )
  .appendTo( 'body' );
```

```css
.alpha + .alpha,
.beta + .beta {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Since the OP clearly stated there is a user id attached to each message, this answer doesn't add anything of value, quite the contrary, as you removed the usage of user id

Comment: I'm going to disagree. You're assuming that the styling of the message element is inextricably tied to the ID/user. The post simply says that the ID is unknown ahead of time. It would be trivial to toggle between two CSS classes, `data-` attribute etc. every time the user ID changed when generating the markup. If the user ID needs to be attached to the markup because the data will be consumed by the app in some way, there's nothing stopping one from adding a custom attribute or a `data-` attribute to make it available.

Comment: Yes _I am assumin that_ since the OP had this `data-user="usr_1"` on each message in the question, and explicit told _usr_0, usr_1, usr_2,... are IDs and therefor can't be hardcoded in the CSS file_, which I again assume they are in markup, and asked how to assign them at runtime

Comment: Are you suggesting that [**something like this**](https://jsfiddle.net/hhywyLsd/) isn't a possible solution?

Comment: Absolute not, just can't understand why you post an almost identical solution to the one already given, and IMHO, didn't add anything extra, simply used a class instead of an attribute as the selector, which is of little value since the real issue is how to assign a CSS value to an element at runtime

Comment: It's not simply swapping an attribute selector for a class selector. Similar, sure. Noted as much. If you think that's all the difference there is, you're not paying attention.

Comment: If you think I am not paying attention, then lets leave it at that and I rest my case